# Web application not working in vs 2019 when selecting iisexpress How do i make this work?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have installed vs 2019 and running a new asp.net core web app, but the project is only running on http://localhost:5000 and when i run using ii express on 44329 port it is failing.
[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings Check if port 44329 has a valid certificate

Comment: Please check the IIS express applicationhost.config file. It has the binding information of this application. Check if the application bind to https and what the port is.

Comment: uninstalled VS2019 and installed again it worked, I believe the IIS server was not  correctly installed.